# Get user email address from Active Directory with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory

Jenkins is configured with Active Directory for authentication.

The job is triggered remotely using REST API based on token and not through the Jenkins UI. One of the parameters passed to the job is userID which is present in the active directory. To send notifications to the user who kicked off the job remotely, how do I retrieve the email address for that user id ?

Comment: might want to add an Active Directory tag.

Comment: here is where it was implemented in Jenkins https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6648

Comment: Thanks Novaterata ! I tried using the classes that were changed to get the details but the methods that are used require Script Approval from Admin. Because these are user related, Jenkins shows a suggestion message on Approval page that approving these scripts might add a security vulnerability. So, this is kind of no from our Security Team

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build user vars plugin to do this. Logging in with LDAP should populate the BUILD_USER_EMAIL parameter. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin